# faster way to color cells in Excel via Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 3 dataframes  difference_df, validatedOutput and initial_output all of same dimension. Also difference_df is defined as below.

```
difference_df = validatedOutput == initial_output
```

I want to write validatedOutput to an Excel file, and color all those values in yellow where validatedOutput != initial_output 
To do the same, I am using a conditional worksheet.write method to color the cells based on the value of difference_df. Below is a sample code :

```
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Upload_Sheet'] 

yellow_format = workbook.add_format()
yellow_format.set_pattern(1)  # This is optional when using a solid fill.
yellow_format.set_bg_color('#FFFF00')

#orange format. This color is for header    
orange_format = workbook.add_format()
orange_format.set_pattern(1)  # This is optional when using a solid fill.
orange_format.set_bg_color('#FFA500')

for i in range(len(difference_df.columns)):
    for j in range(len(difference_df.index)):
        op = validatedOutput.iloc[j,i]
        ip = initial_output.iloc[j,i]

        if pd.isnull(op) and pd.isnull(ip) :
            continue
        elif pd.notnull(op) and difference_df.iloc[j, i]:
            worksheet.write(j+1, i, op)
        elif pd.notnull(op) :
            worksheet.write(j+1, i, op, yellow_format)
```

The problem is this method is incredibly slow and as I am accessing each element of the dataframe using a for loop and then writing it to the file. 
Is there a faster way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to write the two data sets (validated and initial) to two separate areas of the Excel file, e.g. two worksheets, and then use conditional formatting in Excel to do the coloring, rather than specifying colors via Python code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks John, But I was looking for a complete python solution.